# .Net SendMail SMTP Conversation

Tags: .net, smtp

How does the .Net **SendMail** construct/conduct its conversation to the mail server?  Is it just one session (`HELO-->QUIT`) or does it do something wacky like have one conversation for each address?  Are there cases where getting wacky is more prudent?

I'm not interested in the actual conversation, just single|multiple; along with the conditions that make multiple conversations preferable.

Comment: What do you mean by SendMail? There's no such class, the built-in SmtpClient class contains a *very* strong deprecation warning and most people use MailKit.  Besides, how clients and servers talk to each other is controlled by the SMTP, it's not open to interpretaion

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and assume Y is the solution, so when that doesn't work you ask about Y. What is the *actual* problem?